# Input Button (from Forms) and Anchor Buttons Showing Different Sizes Even With Same Dimentions

Tags: css

I'm facing this problem. Height and width are the same for both input button and anchor button but, in the preview screen or even in the browser, the sizes shown are different: input button tends to be smaller. Why? How to fix this? Only the input text field follows the same size as the anchor button.

Input button:

```
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
```

Anchor button:

```
<a href=""><input class="button" type="button" name="submit" value="Add"></a>
```

I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post a small Demo so I can look what the problem.

Comment: just try to give an answer here. Its not clear anything from just pasting the HTML code.

Comment: for sure! here it goes:

Input button:
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">

Anchor button:
<a href=""><input class="button" type="button" name="submit" value="Add"></a>

CSS:
.button{ width:545px; height:65px; }

P.S.: Both Input and Anchor button have the same class ("button"). Theorically, both of them should have the same properties on screen. What happens is that they have the same width and height on the setup but not on the screen. Input button is smaller than Anchor button.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: can you paste your necessary code on this tool and then pass me a link. http://jsbin.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure; what CSS you've applied for class `button` and for `<a>` tag. I am just trying to give an answer here. Well the answer is might be there is some `a` tag css overlapping with class `button`.

I've made a Demo how the `<a>` style affecting  on input field. Here is the ***[Demo.](http://jsbin.com/pibaxotu/1/)***

> **Note:** Just curious Why you wrapping your `input` field inside `<a>` tag. that's wrong approach; Instead of that you should make a
>   javascript function (and define call to action what you want to
>   achive) and then you use call the function using `onclick` Event.

Comment: can I ask you one thing? do you know how to put a clear button right positioned into the password text box by using CSS? this button will clear the password typed wrongly.

Comment: As input fields are inline elements, so you can placed two inputs in same line. here is a Demo. http://jsbin.com/tujeyiqo/1/

Comment: very good, Kheema. but I'd like to do the same as the ones on JQuery text fields, with rounded icon buttons inside the text field and left aligned. would you know how to do this? could you give me a clue?

Comment: okay here you go. only you have to add one image in CSS file. http://jsbin.com/zaxosoho/1

Comment: you are brilliant! from now on I will have you as reference of top web/mobile developer. thanks a lot!